# Is it safe to restart Java after uncaught exception with another Java program?

Tags: java, exception

I am working on a project that has to process **external signals** passed as an input to **Java** program. The signals can be corrupted (i.e. we don't have much control of the input) which may lead to processing errors (such as **DivisionByZeroException**).

What my team wants is that each time uncaught exception is thrown, which causes the Java program to terminate, SOME CODE should **just restart** the Java program **from scratch**.

Therefore, my main question is: *Any danger of writing SOME CODE in the following way?*

MY SOLUTION (SOME CODE will be another Java class):

1. Suppose our Java program is implemented as a **method M of class C** that gets called **once** and **ideally** should run **forever**.
2. I firstly make class C **implement Runnable** interface.
3. I then **override run** method as:

   ```
   class C implements Runnable {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           this.M();
       }

       public void M() {
           // Code for main method to be called ONCE and ideally run FOREVER
           ....
       }

   }
   ```
4. Finally, I create a **wrapper** (called *Recovery* class) around class C to restart C.M() each time an exception is thrown:

   ```
   class Recovery {

     final Object lock = new Object();

     void runAndRecover(final Runnable runnable) { // Will pass an instance of C
         while (true) {
             // Synchronising to make sure that only one instance
             // of runnable input is running at the time.
             synchronized(lock) {
                 try {
                     runnable.run();
                     // Ideally the process should run forever 
                     // (no termination),
                     // and the code of THIS FILE will be blocked HERE
                     // with the runnable RUNNING (which is what we want).
                 } catch (Exception exception) {
                     // If the process was interrupted 
                     // by uncaught exception,
                     // we will restart it.
                     lock.notifyAll();
                 }
             }
         }
     }

   }
   ```

What I hope is that we could run the system as follows:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    C c = new C();
    Recovery recovery = new Recovery();
    recovery.runAndRecover(c);
    // My hope is that code gets blocked HERE and runs REGARDLESS
    // of anything happening inside c. Can I make such assumption?
}
```

A side question: if this approach is not safe, I could then write a shell script to restart the Java program each time exception is thrown. *What would be a simple shell loop to repeatedly execute command **sudo java /path/to/Program**? Is writing a shell script safer?*

Comment: Why don't you just catch the exception ?

Comment: That's what I am doing. Catching and if it gets thrown, restarting the program.

If you ask, why not to catch exception inside method **M**, the answer is that it is quite complicated. M is a big piece of code, which might contain bugs. Also M is meant to be designed in a way that it is **exception free** if the input is **well formated**. For example, we will never divide by number x = 0, if reading x from external input will not assign a value 0 to it. But real data can be corrupted and x might be 0.

Basically, we **can't be sure** that we will catch every possible exception.

Comment: @mercury0114 You can catch all unhandled exception with an [uncaught exception handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-).

Comment: if the crash-recovery approach is all you have i see this a good approach, but as Julien suggested try to handle it in `M()`, worst case usea `try-catch` to wrap the whole body of `m()`, `anyways, make sure you don't re-process same input caused crash when app is recovered, this way you might get stuck in an infinite loop of crash-recovery`

Comment: @Yazan Thx for pointing that I should re-process the same input.

When you said "try to wrap the whole body of **m()** in **try-catch** block", what's the difference between what I am doing?

Comment: when you wrap it , an exception will be handled by `catch` logged somewhere or even just skipped,  the app will not crash or close, it could be handled smoothly, that was my thoughts, not sure about your case if this is applicable.

Comment: But what happens after the exception is caught? Does the program terminate, or keeps, or is restarted?

Comment: if the exception is caught, the app should not crash, but the method could `return` it depends on the way your method is working, and where to place the `try-catch` ex, if you have a loop, place the try-catch inside the loop do not wrap the loop with the try-catch, this way if an iterate crashes the loop will continue, so what will happen is based on the method structure.